# Creating a logic gate simulator with GTK, how to make the placing area?

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, gtk

### Creating a logic gate simulator with GTK interface

***How to make the gate's placing area?***

I wanted to use GTK to benefit from system interface integration but I do not know how to make a widget for this placing area. On this area, we should be able to place gates, connect them together, zoom, move view, select, edit, delete gates, etc...

A widget named GtkFixed can receive freely other widgets and can handle signals about editing, selection, etc... **like** the editing area I want. But I have no idea if **this is** what I want.

So, my questions are the following:

- ***Is there documentation about what I want to do ?***
- ***Am I on the right direction with this GtkFixed widget ?***
- ***If not, what should I use ?*** (maybe the GtkDrawingArea widget ?)

*Edit: After more researches, it seams like what I need is a GtkDrawingArea but using the `cairo` library is like trying to kill a fly with a hammer.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The widget to use is the [`Gtk::DrawingArea`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1DrawingArea.html).

### Steps:

- Create a class inheriting from `Gtk::DrawingArea`.
- Override the default drawing handler by declaring a `bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr);` method in the inheriting class.
- In this function, use the `Cairo::Context` to render whatever you want, here is the [documentation](https://www.cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/classCairo_1_1Context.html).
- This method will be called by `Gtk` every time it is necessary but it can be forced by calling the`queue_draw()` method of the `DrawingArea`.
- Mouse, keyboard and other type of events can be handled by either overriding the event handler or by connecting to the signal a custom function.
- To receive a type of event, a flag has to be set with the `add_events(eventTypeFlag)` method. For the keyboard events, the `DrawingArea` widget has to grab focus.

### Example:

```
class MyClass: Gtk::DrawingArea {
public:
    MyClass() {
        set_can_focus();
        add_events(Gdk::BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | Gdk::KEY_PRESS_MASK);
    }

protected:
    bool on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr) {
        cr->move_to(0, 0);
        cr->rel_line_to(100, 100);
        cr->set_source_rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        cr->set_line_width(6);
        cr->stroke();
        return true;
    }

    bool on_button_press_event(GdkEventButton* event) {
        grab_focus();
        std::cout << "click with button #" << event->button << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    bool on_key_press_event(GdkEventKey* event) {
        std::cout << "key #" << event->keyval << " pressed" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};
```

### Documentation:

- [Gtkmm](https://gtkmm.org/en/documentation.html) and [API doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/annotated.html)
- [Gtk drawing area](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1DrawingArea.html)
- [Cairo context](https://www.cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/classCairo_1_1Context.html)
- [Gdk events](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html)